# How to convert tiny yolov2 model for tensorflow lite model?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolo, darkflow

I've trained a custom tiny yolov2 model and want to use this model in Xamarin Android app. I've converted yolov2 weights file to .pb using darkflow. The converted model don't work in Xamarin Android app and the error comes. This [blog post](https://blog.francium.tech/real-time-object-detection-on-mobile-with-flutter-tensorflow-lite-and-yolo-android-part-a0042c9b62c6) says the .pb model should be converted to tensorflow lite version to run on Android and I've also converted the model to tensorflow lite model but it still gives the error as

> Failed to load model.lite, Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization:
>   Invalid GraphDef

How can I convert tiny yolov2 model to tensorflow lite model to make it working with Android app?

Comment: Were you able to convert your tiny yolov2 weights into .tflite? If yes then can you add a self answer?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide
just follow these steps. 
include tensorflow interpreter and convert your model to tensorflow lite as shown in the link.
are you coding for real time object detection on android?